# A definite article before "silent mode"

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

Why do the natives of the English language not use a definite article before "silent mode" while saying, "My cell-phone is on silent mode."?

Comment: There is only one silent mode. Therefore, "silent mode" being said on the topic of your phone would always refer to the silent mode on your phone.

Comment: Because it's shorter and as clear as with the definite article. 52 posts on zero-article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Which* "natives of the English language" do you have in mind? I ask this because you use *the* before the quoted noun phrase above. And when a native English writer/speaker uses *the*, we are making a definite reference to something. When we make a definite reference to something that is a plural noun phrase, we almost always have a specific group in mind, AND we usually expect that our hearers/readers know which group we are talking about. But here I have no idea which group of native speakers you are talking about.

If you use no article (also called the zero article) before "Native speakers of the English language", you are making an indefinite reference and do not have a specific group in mind; you just mean native speakers of the English language in general.

As far as

> My cell-phone is on silent mode.

First, it would not matter if there were 10,000 available modes. You would still not use an article. Each mode is **already unique**.

This is similar to a location where there could be one million tables, and you would say:

> My cell-phone is on Table 6852.

And we would **not** say *the Table 6852* even though we have a definite table in mind.  It is basically the name of a uniquely identifiable table. And *silent mode* can be considered a uniquely identifiable mode. Just like Stack Exchange uses User##### to uniquely identify users. We don't need the definite article before one item/user/table/mode that can be uniquely identified from others in a certain set of items/users/tables/modes.

As for the preposition, *on* is definitely the one to use, because it fits with already established uses of *on*.

You can shorten your sentence to

> My cell is on silent.
>   My cell is on vibrate.
>   My cell is on loud/ringer.

Just like

> My TV is on mute (mode).
>   My speaker/volume is on low (mode).
>   The heater is on high (mode).

And you can instruct someone to put their phone *on* vibrate or their TV *on* mute.

Using *in* instead of *on* in the above sentences sounds bad.

Note that a person can also be *on hold*--not *in hold*--when waiting for a person to talk to.

Ultimately, it's just a collocation that doesn't require either the definite or indefinite article. We have lots of those, including

I'm *on top* of the world.
The shot is *on target*.
The actors look better *on screen* than face to face.
That football player is *on fire*; he's scored goals in seventeen straight games.

We have collocations with *in* (stand in line) and *at* (be at school) also, but this answer has been long enough.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is short and unambiguous. It uses the same structure as expressing any other *mode* your phone would be in:

> - My phone is **on vibrate**.
> - My phone is **on loud**.

The premodifier (*silent*, *vibrate* or *loud*) already clearly state the type of mode your phone is in. The use of the article here is obsolete and would sound off simply because it is normally omitted when speaking about a phone's current mode.

Comment: Is it okay to say that a phone is **on** a mode? I thougth that the most natural preposition is **in**. It is as if the phone is "inside" the mode, as opposed to it being "on top" of the mode. When the word "mode" is not expressed, "my phone is **on** vibrate" sounds okay to be, but with "mode" added it starts sounding strange..

Comment: Ah yes, if you add the word mode it might be better to use the preposition *in*, I'll change my answer.

Comment: I'd still fall for 'on' mode. The reason I think is the 'button' that most of the phones have. You can either put the button 'on' or 'off'. So, that way, we put our phones 'on' silent mode. Check your Android/iOS phone. You may have a button that reads on/off ;) @CopperKettle

Comment: @MaulikV what is the relation between ON/OFF to 'on' as a preposition for mode? That seems so irrelevant!

Comment: @Ahmad perhaps it might happened that semantically, they started using 'phone silent mode is 'on'' that later might have coined that saying? When we see some options on 'screen', it genreally takes 'on' as you play songs 'on' phone. But then if it's inside, inherited, it's 'in' as you have Android system *in* your phone. Silent mode is visible 'on' screen so... maybe...perhaps....my guess! :)